# How to set optional parameter in a django url?

Tags: django, url

I have write down this code in a url

```
path('list/<str:name>', GetList.as_view(), name = "getList" )
```

my view.py

```
class BlogList(View):
  def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
```

now i want to set name as optional parameter with list it show show all and with name i will implement query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to do this, One simple approach is to have multiple rules that matches your needs, all pointing to the same view.

```py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^project_config/$', views.foo),
    url(r'^project_config/(?P<product>\w+)/$', views.foo),
    url(r'^project_config/(?P<product>\w+)/(?P<project_id>\w+)/$', views.foo),
)
```

Also keep in mind that in your view you'll also need to set a default for the optional URL parameter, or you'll get an error:

```py
def foo(request, optional_parameter=''):
    # Your code goes here
```

##### For Django version > 2.0

Similar approach , but syntax

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('project_config/',views.foo,name='project_config'),
    path('project_config/<product>/',views.foo,name='project_config'),
    path('project_config/<product>/<project_id>/',views.foo,name='project_config'),
]
```

Comment: please done copy and paste ans it not working and watch my  code i am using class view ok

Comment: Copy pasting won't work, what I shown here is just example on how to implement

Comment: with class view ?

Comment: path('list/', BlogList.as_view(), name = "bloglist" ),
  path('list/<str:tag_slug>', BlogList.as_view(), name = "bloglist" ),
i have added 2 url